# jquery function cannot send ajax request to django server

Tags: javascript, jquery, python, ajax, django

**Ajax code cannot send request to server, but when I make regular http request to the same url, it can work. I have tried to substitute the url field to the "http://" url, still cannot work. Anybody has idea?**

```
Environment:

django 1.5.4;
python 2.7.4;
jquery 2.0.3;
```

**test.html**

```
<html>
    <head>
            <title></title>
            <script type='text/javascript' src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.0.3.min.js"></script>
            <script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function() {
                    $("#button").click(function(){
                            $.ajax({
                                    type : "POST",
                                    url : "{% url 'getlist' %}",
                                    data : {
                                            msg : 'abcd'
                                    },
                            }).done(function(data){
                                    alert(data.message);
                            });
                    });
            });     
            </script>
    </head>
    <body>
            <input id="button" type="button" value="Get message from server!">
            {% if resource_list %}
            <ul>
                    {% for resource in resource_list %}
                    <li><a href="{{ resource.url }}">{{ resource.name }}</a></li>
                    {% endfor %}
            </ul>
            {% else %}
            <p>No Resources</p>
            {% endif %}
    </body>
```

**view.py**

```
def getList(request):
    print "Reach getLists"
    if request.is_ajax():
            try:
                    msg = request.POST['msg']
            except:
                    return HttpResponse(simplejson.dumps({'message':'Error From Server'}))
            return HttpResponse(simplejson.dumps({'message':msg}))
    else:
            return HttpResponse(simplejson.dumps({'message':'Not an ajax request'}))
```

**urls.py**

```
url(r'^test$', views.test),
url(r'^getlist/$', views.getList, name='getlist'),
```

==================================== Update =====================================
Error Info

```
Forbidden (403)
```

CSRF verification failed. Request aborted.
Help
Reason given for failure:
    CSRF token missing or incorrect.

============================== Resolved ==================================
Solution: After add "csrfmiddlewaretoken:'{{ csrf_token }}', " in data field of JavaScript file, it worked. The reason is django has enabled CSRF protection.

============================== Thanks ====================================
Thanks to the help of @dkp2442 and @Christian Ternus, especially @dkp2442.

Comment: What errors are you getting? Does the `"Reach getLists"` message appear? Can you see anything in your Javascript and/or Django consoles?

Comment: Have you viewed source on the rendered template to make sure the `{% url 'getlist' %}` is working properly?

Comment: @Christian Ternus The "Reach getLists" message cannot show when click the button, but it shows when accessed by browser's http request. Previously, I added an alert to show the error information, and the information is 403: undefined.

Comment: @dpk2442 After render, the {% url 'getlist' %} in ajax code has been substituted by /getlist/.

Comment: If you are using a browser like Chrome, when you look at the javascript console, is anything printed when you click the button?

Comment: @dpk2442 Here is the error info:POST http://www.remainfortest.com/getlist/ 403 (FORBIDDEN) jquery-2.0.3.js:7845
x.support.cors.e.crossDomain.send jquery-2.0.3.js:7845
x.extend.ajax jquery-2.0.3.js:7301
(anonymous function) test:8
x.event.dispatch jquery-2.0.3.js:4676
y.handle

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well I created a [gist](https://gist.github.com/goldhand/3a4e2fef46a0ec1d9e5d) but made it secret somehow (can I edit that?? lol).  Anyway, you need to include the csrftoken in your post. Here is my answer:

```
    function getCookie(name) {
        var cookieValue = null;
        if (document.cookie && document.cookie != '') {
            var cookies = document.cookie.split(';');
            for (var i = 0; i < cookies.length; i++) {
                var cookie = jQuery.trim(cookies[i]);
                // Does this cookie string begin with the name we want?
                if (cookie.substring(0, name.length + 1) == (name + '=')) {
                    cookieValue = decodeURIComponent(cookie.substring(name.length + 1));
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        return cookieValue;
    }
```

You can use that getCookie function for any of your posts, just include it like so:

```
     $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#button").click(function(){
            $.ajax({
                type : "POST",
                url : "{% url 'getlist' %}",
                data : {
                    msg : 'abcd',
                    csrfmiddlewaretoken: getCookie('csrftoken')
                }
            }).done(function(data){
                alert(data.message);
            });
        });
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Read the [ajax section](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/csrf/#ajax) on the django docs page on csrf.